TypeError: object int can't be used in 'await' expression
Использую библиотеку redis==5.0.4
Решил сформировать стек:
from redis import Redis
from fastapi import FastAPI

def get_client(db: int=0) -> Redis:
    return Redis(host=REDIS_IP, port=REDIS_PORT, db=db)

app = FastAPI()

@APP.get("/")
async def index() -> dict:
    client_redis = get_client()
    await client_redis.lpush('stack', str(10))
    await client_redis.lpush('stack', str(20))
    return {'succes': True}

Когда открываю страницу выпадает ошибка:
await client_redis.lpush('stack', str(10))
TypeError: object int can't be used in 'await' expression

В каком он месте видит число? Я же явно обернул в str.
UPD для комментария: Pycharm выделял строку пока не добавил await перед строкой:



В каком он месте видит число?

В возвращаемом значении client_redis.lpush, к которому, собственно, и применяется await.

Получается что асинхронно это нельзя делать?

@Алексей, await не делает функцию асинхронной.

докинул UPD. От меня PyCharm требовал дописать await - я написал, что в итоге и породило ошибку. Да, я в курсе, что await - это ожидание выполнения инструкции в асинхронной функции

я убрал async и await и ошибка исчезла, поэтому я и спросил, что получается нельзя формировать стек в асинхронной функции
